# transition to Xcode 6.01 yes or no

Tags: xcode6

I'm currently developing an app for iOS 7.1 and I was wondering if I should update my Xcode  from 5.1.1 to 6.0.1.
My main concern is that I have to use the new Swift programming anguange and can't use the objective-c I just learned, or if I still can use the objective-c in Xcode 6.01 and target iOS 7.1.

What is your experience, am I going to face problems with my current project after updating?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to program in Swift. Objective-C works just fine. That being said I like Swift. You would do well to learn it.

Comment: Swift is another option that makes things easier for few people like me. You can still certainly  use Objective-C with no issues.

Comment: Yeahhh! :-) Thanks for the reply, appreciate you taking the time. I just got familiar with Objective-C, but I'll give it a try! Thx again